# Discrepance between Usage Report in Here Developer Portal and total transactions in usage alerts emails

Tags: here-api

during the weekend I have received several emails from Here Platform about the limits of my freemium plan.

On 6th May the first email say that I have reached 125.000 transactions, however in the usage report in developer portal, within the current billig, until 7th May the total transactions is 98.000.

Again yesterday 8th May I received three emails with alerts about usage jumping in four hours from  180.000 to 250.000 and thats it's impossible because there wasn't peak of traffic in my website. Still the usage report is not update with the yesterday data and I can't confirm those data.

Are that discrepances normal or there is a technical issue with the alert emails?

Has Here Platform security filters if someone use my api credentials? I have configured trusted domain but maybe that can't be enought, right?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same thing and unfortunately it's not just the "Looks like you’ve been busy" email warnings, it has also led to an actual plan suspension. I've apparently used up 250,000 transaction credits just two days in to my monthly billing cycle, whereas I've always had spare at the end of the month previously, and there has been no corresponding increase in traffic to my site.

For me this problem started last month and I was waiting until my new billing period to begin a few days ago to see if the issue had been resolved. Clearly it hasn't. Not only are the usage figures reported in the emails way above my expectations they are also completely out of kilter with the here.com developer console. When I first noticed the problem the console was showing about 3,000 uses, when the warning was claiming 230,000.

I emailed them about it two weeks ago but haven't had a reply yet.